# codeigniter search filter model

Tags: codeigniter

I have created a search filter with my pagination model, When I type in my filter it does not pick up if I just have **one letter** for some reason my model requires that I have **min 2** letters to start filtering

What is the best method in model so my search field can pick up just **one letter** typed in the filter input.

```
public function getUserGroups($limit = null, $offset = NULL) {
    $this->db->select("user_group_id, name");
    $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'user_group');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');
    $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'user_group_id' => $this->input->post('user_group_id')
    );
    $this->db->like($data);
    $this->db->or_like('name', 'match');
    $this->db->or_like('user_group_id', 'match');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: why you added `$this->db->or_like('name', 'match');
    $this->db->or_like('user_group_id', 'match');`? Do you really want to search `match` word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following query will solve your problem

```
public function getUserGroups($limit = null, $offset = NULL) //better use $limit=0,$offset=0
{
$this->db->select("user_group_id, name");
$this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'user_group');
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');
$data = array(
    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
    'user_group_id' => $this->input->post('user_group_id')
);
$this->db->or_like($data);    
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Remember**
They way you using `like` and `or_like` may produce wrong query.Make sure your query is producing right way as you wanted